# New root category not displayed in seperate website

Tags: magento-1.9, category

To display different category in different website,

1. Created new root category.
2. Created new website, store, store view at backend and used that newly created root category in it.
3. Then created a subdirectory in domain `127.0.0.1/magento/magento2` where `magento2` is the created subdirectory.
4. copied `index.php` and `htaccess` from domain into created subdirectory (magento2).
5. Then changed `$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';` to `$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../app/Mage.php';` in index.php
6. Then inserted

   `SetEnvIf Host .*base.* MAGE_RUN_CODE="base";`

   `SetEnvIf Host .*magento_site_2.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE="leap_in_en"`

   where `leap_in_en` is the unique code code of my store view.
7. At backend after switching to new website in configuration scope, changed the unsecure and secure url to `127.0.0.1/magento/magento2`.
8. Now when I enter the url `127.0.0.1/magento/magento2` in the browser. It is displaying the old store with same category not the new root category.

Someone please tell me where have I went wrong or is there any additional thing that I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got The answer...! 
I just forgot to change `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);` to      `Mage::run('leap_in_en', $mageRunType);` in index.php where `leap_in_en` is my unique store view code.